# C++ File handling error

Tags: c++, file, filestream

what to do?while you are trying to answer this question try to be more noob specific.
No additional details. i am getting an error

> ```
> no match for operator<< in theFileIn<<number
> ```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number;
string name;

ofstream theFileOut;
ifstream theFileIn;

theFileOut.open("Sansa.txt");
cout << "Enter the number and the name"<<endl;

while(cin>> number>> name)
{
    theFileOut<<number<<" "<<name<<endl;
}

theFileOut.close();
theFileIn.open("sansa.txt");

while(theFileIn>>number>>name)
{
    theFileIn << number<<" "<<name<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is at least the 3rd question you post today regarding file input\output. Please study first of all at least a little your topic because none of your question are imposible to find answer if you do at least some research on your own.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the exact error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what's wrong:

```
theFileIn<<number<<" "<<name<<endl;
```

You need to switch `theFileOut` in something else, best is with `cout`.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with `theFileOut`. OP read `number` and `name` from `cin` and write it to file, which is right. Then OP tried to read from a different file (possible typo in filename, I guess OP means the file just created) and output read content on screen, this step has errors.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here:

```
  theFileIn << number<<" "<<name<<endl;
```

`theFileIn` is `ifstream` object, you cannot use `<<` with ifstream object. You probably mean:

```
 cout << number<<" "<<name<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank you taocp, that explains everything

Comment: @Noob.Alone.Programmer You are welcome. Try to understand the difference between `<<` and `>>` and read some tutorial about C++ FILE I/O.

Comment: Beat me to it! @Noob.Alone.Programmer Don't forget to accept the answer!